# fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com ': No such device or address - rubyonrails - aws

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a rubyonrails website which function in such a way that when a user signup with his username it create a repo in that username in my github account. It is working flawlessly in heroku. When I switched to amazon web service I initially get

```
intializing git
sh: git: command not found
sh: line 0: cd: /home/webapp: No such file or directory
```

I overcome this error by adding a config file in `.ebextensions` like

```
commands:
  01_mkdir_webapp_dir:
    # use the test directive to create the directory
    # if the mkdir command fails the rest of this directive is ignored
    test: 'mkdir /home/webapp'
    command: 'ls -la /home/webapp'
  02_chown_webapp_dir:
    command: 'chown webapp:webapp /home/webapp'
  03_chmod_webapp_dir:
    command: 'chmod 700 /home/webapp'
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
```

Then I have a new error log like

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com ': No such device or address
```

As a side note when I run this script locally, and I signed up the site at localhost:3000 terminal prompt me to submit github username and password. Is that normal. Is this is the cause of the error `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com ': No such device or address`.
But this code works flawlessly in heroku.

Full log is below.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yPYsS1ETHhrEoYFWHJxt4y52jHYRkooj/view?usp=sharing

I have these environment set in aws.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/GeQHXdUWUMuixTgNA

Comment: hello again, i wouldn't touch weabpp folder, coz it's already done for you be EB

Comment: try to provide full path to git command /usr/bin/git

Comment: Still it asks for github username and password in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try to create git config file directly

```
#/home/webapp/.gitconfig
[user]
    name = soumjoyel
    email = soumjoyel@gmail.com
```

using this script

```
files:
  "/home/webapp/.gitconfig" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: webapp
    group: webapp
    content: |
      [user]
        name = soumjoyel
        email = soumjoyel@gmail.com
```

Comment: Still same error, `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address`.

Comment: How to know that. I have thease errors[isolated] in complete logs https://pastebin.com/C3p3sTuM  Puma log https://pastebin.com/wvcRGMXg

Comment: to get rid of one error, add -p option to -> mkdir -p /home/webapp'

Comment: did it create .gitconfig file?

Comment: Sorry here is the correct puma log https://pastebin.com/r1Dv9NxS How to check .gitconfig file is created?

Comment: try to change approach to connect to git, switch https to git. then you need to have ssh key at /home/webapp/.ssh file

Comment: `cd home/webapp` gives `bash: cd: webapp: Permission denied`.

Comment: under root? ls -la /home/webapp

Comment: ssh as ec2 user. `ls -la /home/webapp` gives `ls: cannot open directory /home/webapp: Permission denied`

Comment: do "sudo -s" first

Comment: ssh -i key webapp@public dns gives `Permission denied (publickey)`

Comment: webapp folder is empty

Comment: i asked about it's permissions ls -la /home/webapp

Comment: Sorry is not empty it contains .gitconfig with `[user]
    name = soumjoyel
    email = soumjoyel@gmail.com`

Comment: `drwx------ 3 webapp webapp 4096 Jan 31 14:12 `

Comment: it contain .netrc which is empty file

Comment: do deploy again

Comment: We didn't change anything, Why redo dpeloy?

Comment: even better rebuild

Comment: New error `Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
` when i tried ssh instead hhtp

Comment: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
`and the repository exists.`

Comment: Using ssh instead git locally was succeeded. In aws I get `Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`